# Office.js проверка версии word

Tags: office, office.js

Наткнулся, что есть версии Word 2016, которые не поддерживаются для работы с office js.
Как отслеживать такие версии? (скриншоты для примера)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: что значит "отслеживать"?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение

```
Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported('WordApi', 1.3)
```

Вернет false, если текущая версия Word не поддерживает эту версию API
(Частая проблема для Word 2016 (MSO 16.0.4266.1001) и Word 2016 с VL)